# Terrain Height Map - C++/Vertex Shader has different values

Tags: c++, hlsl, terrain, mipmaps, heightmap

I have been working on a terrain and have had to come to a complete stop. I am programming in C++, DirectX9 and HLSL to create the terrain but I am also using height maps that are BMP format. I am loading the information in from the height map in both the C++ side as well as the shader side. On the C++ side, I am using D3DXCreateTextureFromFile and surfaces (D3DXSaveSurfaceToFile) to load the information, whereas on the shader side, I am using tex2Dlod to load my information for the terrain vertices. These two are getting different values from the height map. Upon further research, I found out that the tex2Dlod function utilizes mip maps (still don't understand those fully) to load the information.

Would anyone know a way on how to get the two numbers to match up? If you need more information (the numbers, pictures or whatever) just let me know!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First  question  is  why do you  stick  with DX9  what  is  a reason ?  I would understand  at least  DX10. Can u show me  HLSL code ?

tex2Dlod  is  the  texture  sampling function which takes two params. 1.  sampler2D 2. float4(texture coordinates).

Actualy  tex2dlod is  the function  which does  texture mip maping(detailing  of textures) and  texel offsetting.  But  fully i  did not understand  where is problem ?  Could u be  more specific ?

And by the  way  entire  function  only  supported in  shader model 3.0 at least.